# Java-Stream, toMap with duplicate keys

Tags: java, java-stream

So there might be one abc for several payments, now I have:

```
//find abc id for each payment id
Map<Long, Integer> abcIdToPmtId = paymentController.findPaymentsByIds(pmtIds)
          .stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(Payment::getAbcId, Payment::getPaymentId));
```

But then I reallize this could have duplicate keys, so I want it to return a

```
Map<Long, List<Integer>> abcIdToPmtIds
```

which an entry will contain one abc and his several payments.

I know I might can use `groupingBy` but then I think I can only get `Map<Long, List<Payments>>` .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the other groupingBy overload.

```
paymentController.findPaymentsByIds(pmtIds)
      .stream()
      .collect(
          groupingBy(Payment::getAbcId, mapping(Payment::getPaymentId, toList());
```

Comment: Great answer! For those we need slightly modified version to include to whole payment in the map instead of only the id: `.collect(groupingBy(Payment::getId, mapping(payment -> payment, toList())))`

Answer (score 4):

Problem statement: Converting `SimpleImmutableEntry<String, List<String>>` -> `Map<String, List<String>>`.

For Instance you have a SimpleImmutableEntry of this form [A,[1]], [B,[2]], [A, [3]] and you want your map to looks like this: A -> [1,3] , B -> [2].

This can be done with `Collectors.toMap` but Collectors.toMap works only with unique keys unless you provide a merge function to resolve the collision as said in java docs.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-

So the example code looks like this:

```
          .map(returnSimpleImmutableEntries)
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey,
                                    SimpleImmutableEntry::getValue,
                                    (oldList, newList) -> { oldList.addAll(newList); return oldList; } ));
```

returnSimpleImmutableEntries method returns you entries of the form [A,[1]], [B,[2]], [A, [3]] on which you can use your collectors.

Answer (score 3):

With `Collectors.toMap`:

```
Map<Long, Integer> abcIdToPmtId = paymentController.findPaymentsByIds(pmtIds)
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Payment::getAbcId, 
        p -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(p.getPaymentId())),
        (o, n) -> { o.addAll(n); return o; }));
```

Though it's more clear and readable to use `Collectors.groupingBy` along with `Collectors.mapping`.

You don't need streams to do it though:

```
Map<Long, Integer> abcIdToPmtId = new HashMap<>();
paymentController.findPaymentsByIds(pmtIds).forEach(p ->
    abcIdToPmtId.computeIfAbsent(
            p.getAbcId(),
            k -> new ArrayList<>())
        .add(p.getPaymentId()));
```

Comment: Excellent, That's the thing I was hunting.